# Spring Data. Change DB user credentials at runtime

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

There is Spring Boot Aplication. For forking with DB I use Spring Data (JPA + Repository).

Is there way to change DB user-credentials for datasource per API user-request? I mean each MVC request must do his own work with exactly his DB user-credentials.

I've read info about AbstractRoutingDataSource. But there is limitation: there isn't possibility to add datasource at runtime in DataSourceMap.

In fact I want to use apache PerUserPoolDataSource and change DB user-credentials (using Spring Security Context to get user information)

Comment: What about using Dynamic DataSource Routing https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/ it helps you?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed I saw this article - there is limitation. All datasorces must be defined before deployment (not at runtime). Not my case unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution. First of all need to define custom datasource configuration.

```
@Bean
    public UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSource() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        final UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dataSourceAdapter = new UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter();
        dataSourceAdapter.setTargetDataSource(perUserPoolDataSource());
        return dataSourceAdapter;
    }

    private PerUserPoolDataSource perUserPoolDataSource() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        DriverAdapterCPDS driverAdapter = new DriverAdapterCPDS();
        driverAdapter.setDriver(properties.getDriverClassName());
        driverAdapter.setUrl(properties.getUrl());
        driverAdapter.setUser(properties.getUsername());//default
        driverAdapter.setPassword(properties.getPassword());//default
        driverAdapter.setAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed(true);

        PerUserPoolDataSource dataSource = new PerUserPoolDataSource();
        dataSource.setConnectionPoolDataSource(driverAdapter);

        return dataSource;
    }
```

As you see - there is base datasource from Apache: `PerUserPoolDataSource`.
Also as main datasource I will use `UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter`.

Then need to write custom filter, which will change user credentials for successefully authenticated users:

```
dataSourceAdapter.setCredentialsForCurrentThread(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
```

This solution works for blocked paradygm (not reactive). One thread with credentials for specific user will do all queries.